# Trying to get iOS device token by using firebase message in React Native

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

Below is the steps implemented in React Native code -
Do i have to add any steps or methods in iOS side?
Certificate is APNS enable.

Step 1:

```
# Install & setup the app module
yarn add @react-native-firebase/app

# Install the messaging module
yarn add @react-native-firebase/messaging

# If you're developing your app using iOS, run this command
cd ios/ && pod install


const getDeviceToken = firebase.messaging().getAPNSToken();
  if (getDeviceToken) {
    console.log('getDeviceToken:', getDeviceToken);
  }
```

But the result i am getting in console is : { _U: 0, _V: 0, _W: null, _X: null }
Note: I am running the project in Actual iOS device.
Notification permission is already granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firebase.messaging().getAPNSToken() returns a promise.
You can get your token when the promise is reloved like this:

```
getDeviceToken.then( async (token) => {
  console.log('promise token: ', token);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it async in order to wait for the token to be fetched from firebase

use `async` `await` and it will work

```
const getDeviceToken = await firebase.messaging().getAPNSToken();
  if (getDeviceToken) {
    console.log('getDeviceToken:', getDeviceToken);
  }
```